# "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class"

Tags: excel, vba

This code has been working for ages. I thought maybe I accidently pressed a key but I cannot seem to see it. I suddenly get the error:

**Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class**

in the below code:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + k, x + j).Select
TempValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + k, x + j).Value
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + k, x + j).NumberFormat = "#,##0" //ERROR HERE
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y + k, x + j).Value = TempValue
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `TempValue` when you get that error? The line where you get your error looks ok.

Comment: Also what is the value of `y` , `k`, `x`, `j` at the time of error?

Comment: y,k,x,j are completely fine- 6,0,2,1. TempValue = -30081207.13

Comment: Is your Sheet Protected?

Comment: @Siddharth, I haven't explicitly changed it today and this code was working earlier

Comment: I understand. Can you manually check if the sheet is protected?

Comment: Did you check if it is protected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11881/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1107474)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem as discovered in Chat was the workbook had more than 64,000 formats because of which the user was getting the "**Too many different cell formats**" error message in Excel

Solution

**Topic: You receive a "Too many different cell formats" error message in Excel**

**Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213904

**QUOTE from the above link**

> In Microsoft Excel 2007/2010 files may produce the following error message;
>
> Excel found unreadable content in the file
>
> This problem occurs when the workbook contains more than approximately 4,000 different combinations of cell formats in Excel 2003 or 64,000 in Excel 2007 and higher.

Solution as mentioned in the link is to download and run the [XLStyesTool](http://sergeig888.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/net4-0-version-of-the-xlstylestool-is-now-available/)

Answer (score 2):

I met with this problem using Fuzzy LookUp AddIn in Office365ProPlus.
After I run FuzzyLookUp only 10 rows of output were generated and this message popped up.

Problem was caused by my local setting of Excell.

To fix it I had to change decimal separator from coma into dot under general Excel settings.

On my side it solved the problem perfectly.