# Apply format to many excel cells at once

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to format all added values in my excel file and i have a "small" and "fast" solution like this:

`Item2` is a `List<string>`, `Item3` is a `List<List<string>>`

```
if (chkWithValues.Checked && results.Item3.Any())
{
    var rows = results.Item3.Count;
    var cols = results.Item3.Max(x => x.Count);
    object[,] values = new object[rows, cols];
    object[,] format = new object[rows, cols];

    //All returned items are inserted into the Excel file
    //Item2 contains the database types, Item3 the Values
    // pgMain shows the progress for the selected tables
    for (int j = 0; j < results.Item3.Count(); j++)
    {
        int tmpNbr = 1;

        foreach (string value in results.Item3[j])
        {
            values[j, tmpNbr - 1] = Converter.Convert(results.Item2[tmpNbr - 1], value).ToString().Replace("'", "");
            format[j, tmpNbr - 1] = ExcelColumnTypes.ConvertToExcelTypes(results.Item2[tmpNbr - 1]);
            tmpNbr++;
        }                            
        pgMain.Maximum = results.Item3.Count();
        pgMain.PerformStep();
    }
    Excel.Range range = xlWorksheet.Range["A3", GetExcelColumnName(cols) + (rows + 2)];
    range.Value = values;
    range.NumberFormat = format;
}
```

To add the numberformat efficiently with a single assignment, I've found a solution with a 2d array, which contains all number formats that should be set.

The problem is that I get the following error message `"Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class"` when I have more than (i think) `50.000` cells to format.

Does someone know a solution that is fast and can handle a large amount of cells without error?

update:
ExcelColumnTypes.ConvertToExcelTypes

```
public static string ConvertToExcelTypes(string databaseType)
        {
            if (DatabaseColumnTypes.DOUBLE.Contains(databaseType))
                return DOUBLEPO1;
            if (DatabaseColumnTypes.DATE.Contains(databaseType))
                return DATE2;
            if (DatabaseColumnTypes.INTEGER.Contains(databaseType))
                return INT;
            return TEXT;
        }
```

The DatabaseColumnTypes are List with const or direct const.
Sample:

```
public const string VARBINARY = "varbinary";

 public static List<string> STRING = new List<string>()
        {
            CHAR,
            VARCHAR,
            TEXT,
            NTEXT,
            NCHAR,
            NVARCHAR,
            BINARY,
            VARBINARY
        };
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on `ExcelColumnTypes.ConvertToExcelTypes`?

Comment: [See this related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801537/unable-to-set-the-numberformat-property-of-the-range-class). I suspect that your actual amount of different number formats is not exceeding the limit but Excel fails to merge multiple format objects with the same settings. So a solution will likely be a way to reuse a format that is once introduced to Excel.

Comment: I don't know  how important the "NumberFormat " is but when you try the NumberFormatLocal should it work...

Comment: I've tried it and it worked...:) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the

```
range.NumberFormat = format;

range.NumberFormatLocal = format;
```

Then it should work

Comment: Interesting. Do you know *why* it works this way? MSDN is not very specific on the `NumberFormatLocal` property.

Comment: it was a lucky shot, i've tried it and it works, i see there no real difference between these two formats