# C# Excel Number Format error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm having troubles setting columns format in Excel with Interop. I'm using C#, below is the code:

```
Excelop.Range rg = (Excelop.Range)wb.Worksheets[1].Cells[1, i];
rg.NumberFormat = "@"; //Exception is raised here
```

I get the below exception when compiled:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class"

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your worksheet is protected.

You likely need to do something like:

`wb.Worksheets[1].Unprotect (Password:"your_password")`

These may be of assistance:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/449829-run-time-error-1004-unable-set-numberformat-property-range-class.html

["Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801537/unable-to-set-the-numberformat-property-of-the-range-class)